# Angular 2+ reactive form input required only if in the DOM

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ng-if

I'm currently dynamically generating a form input using *ngIf and if this form input us in the DOM it is a required input however if it is not it should not be required.

How can I achieve this using the reactive forms approach?

HTML

```
<select formControlName="input" name="input">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="input === '2'">
   <textarea formControlName="inputDynamic" name="inputDynamic" type="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

COMPONENT

```
initApplicants() {
  return this.fb.group({  
    input: ['', Validators.required],
    inputDynamic: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Let me know if you require any further details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep to the reactive approach you may want to add and remove validators when your app runs. Subscribe to changes first:

```
this.formName.controls['input'].valueChanges().subscribe(value => {
    if (value === 2) {
        //remove validators
    } else {
        //add validators
    }
});
```

`this.formName.controls['controlName'].setValidators(null)` will remove validators.
`this.formName.controls['controlName'].setValidators(Validators.required)` will add validator.

don't forget to call `this.formName.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity()` after you do these operations.

Comment: Hi Alex, have you got an example of this for me to look at? i haven't been able to get it to work yet. thanks

Comment: Just write function which will remove validator and add a validator. removeValidator() {this.formName.controls['controlName'].setValidators(null); this.formName.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity();} addValidator(this.formName.controls['controlName'].setValidators(Validators.required); this.formName.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity();) {}

Answer (score 0):

Using `*ngIf` input will be loaded/removed again  so the better way to use validations with template.

Set **required** in element like this:

```
<div *ngIf="input === '2'">
   <textarea required formControlName="inputDynamic" name="inputDynamic" type="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

and remove from component:

```
initApplicants() {
  return this.fb.group({  
    input: ['', Validators.required],
    inputDynamic: ['', Validators.required] <===== Remove required from here (used in template)
  });
}
```